# pivot и неизвестное кол-во полей

Tags: sql, delphi, sql-server, pivot

Пытаюсь транспонировать таблицу которая на выходе будет иметь не известное кол-во полей.

```
declare @col varchar(max)
      , @query   nvarchar(max)
select @col = coalesce(@col+', ['+cast([tres] as varchar)+']', '['+cast([tres] as varchar)+']')
from [res]
where [id_r] = 1
group by [tres]
set @query = '
declare @sdate date = ''20150101''
      , @fdate date = ''20150120''
select *
from (select [tres]
            ,date
            ,doc
      from [res]
      where [id_r] = 1
        and [date] between @sdate and @fdate) AS stbl
pivot (max(doc) for [tres] IN ('+@col+')) AS pvt;
'
execute [sp_executesql] @query
```

Проблема заключается в том, что если данные удалось найти, получаю нормальный результат в виде таблицы.
Но если указать не существующий "[id_r]", запрос вернет что-то вроде "Выполнение команд успешно завершено.". т.е. ничего!
Из-за этого при попытке выполнить запрос в Delphi используя "ADOQuery.Open;", получаю ошибку "CommandText does not return a result set".
Понимаю, что проблема в "получении" полей, но вот решить проблему без извращений не получается пока.
Подскажите решение!?

Comment: можно решить через NULLIF

Comment: [res] статическая таблица?

Comment: @NickProskuryakov ее поля неизменны

Comment: Количество полей и их названия можно получить из схемы БД, и обернуть все это динамическим Pivot